# Design Powershell script for find the Numbers which contain file

Tags: powershell

Everyone help to design the script to find the Numbers which contain file..

For example:

## 20200514_EE#998501_12.

I need numbers 12 then write to the txt file

the contain will generated different sequence numbers..
For example: #20200514_EE#998501_123.#

so, I need numbers 123 then write to the txt file

How to write the script in Powershell or bat file ?

Very appreciate!

Thanks

Tony

Comment: you can use the split method to split the string with _ (get the last item), then split it with a period (get the first item). BTW SO is not a script writing service, you need to provide your work that you are having issues with

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following as a start. You have not provided enough information/examples to work through any issues you are experiencing.

```
'#20200514_EE#998501_123.#' -replace '^.*?(\d+)\D*$','$1'
'#20200514_EE#998501_123' -replace '^.*?(\d+)\D*$','$1'
```

`-replace` uses regex matching and then replaces with a string and/or matched substitute. `^` is the start of the string. `.*?` lazily matches all characters. `\d+` matches one or more digits in a capture group due to the encapsulating `()`. `\D*` matches zero or more non-digits. `$` matches the end of the string. For the replacement, `$1` is capture group `1`, which is what was captured by `(\d+)`.

---

You can use the `.Split()` method also in combination with `-replace`.

```
'#20200514_EE#998501_123.#'.Split('_')[-1] -replace '\D+$'
```